# generating perpendicular normals from 8-point cube

Tags: 3d, directx, shader, cube, normals

I think I'm just being really dumb right now but I can't seem to think of a really nice way to do this:

Basically I am creating a load of cubes in DirectX and using VertexPositionColor to store the data. To store the cubes efficiently I'm just storing 8 points per cube. The thing is though, I want the normal of each face to point away such that the front face's normal is something like (0, 0, 1) and the back face's normal is (0, 0, -1).

My problem is working out how do this efficiently from only 8-point cubes. I know I could easily do it with a 24-point cube representation but this just seems inefficient from a memory point-of-view.

Any ideas how I can do this? Preferably in the shader or something efficient?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use indecies to save some memory, this would be 8x4 floats + 4*6 ints for each side, that would be 56*4 bytes instead of 96*4 bytes, but that is all you can do, unless some points are shared between cubes.

Answer (score 0):

With shader model 3 or less you have to duplicate the vertices unless it's ok to overage the 3 normals at each vertex.

In shader model 3+ you can expose the index buffer to the shader and use SV_VertexID to compute the normal from 3 vertices in the vertex/hull shader but you can't send it to next stages as you always output 8 vertices.

In the geometry/domain shader you can see triangles from which you can compute normals.

Duplicating the cube vertices is OK and since you’re creating a load of cubes use **geometry instancing**.